# Changing of function arguments

Tags: arguments

I have a function `workbench-named` declared as follows, that calls another one called `workbench`.  Have changed `workbench` to include a prefix argument.  Thusly `workbench-named` is not calling `workbench` properly as it assumes that name is the first argument.

How can I modify the call to `workbench` from the function `workbench-named`?

```lisp
    (defun workbench-named ()
      "Generate new temporary buffer by asking for buffer name."
      (interactive)
      (workbench (read-from-minibuffer " Name: ")))
    
    (defun workbench (&optional prefix name mode)
      "Make new temporary buffer.")
```

Comment: `(workbench nil (read-from-minibuffer " Name: ")))` to provide the expected first argument.

Comment: @FranBurstall: you might want to make your comment into an answer - I believe it answers the question.

Comment: The question is quite unclear. But yes, @FranBurstall has cut to the chase (please post your answer). The question has nothing to do with any "prefix" or "prefix argument" - there isn't any such thing in any of the code shown. And the code was unparsable - doc string without ending `"`, etc.

Comment: Those were minor things.  The focus was about how to call `workbench` rather than worrying about any ending `"`.

Comment: Typically, you don't need two functions to do things like this. Instead, use `(interactive "sName: ")` to make the function ask for a name when called as a command, but use the argument passed to it when called as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to supply just one optional argument, you need to also provide values for preceding arguments in the function's signature.  Thus, in this case,

```
(workbench nil (read-from-minibuffer " Name: ")))
```

does the job.